# Creating n*n matrix from text file contains list of lists in python

Tags: python, list, matrix, vector

I have a text file contains a list (#lines = 1137) of vectors (all are equal size= 1137), am trying to convert this list to 1137*1137 matrix. I created an empty matrix using numpy. But the problem after when I read the file using the following code, the vectors are treated as a sequence of characters, not as a vector or array

```
myMtrx = np.empty((1137,1137))
f = open("text.txt", "r")
for vector in f:
    print len(vector) 
    arrayF.append(vector.rstrip())
```

I recognized that by printing our the length of each vector, which is computed based on number of digits not elements in that vector. The vector in the text file looks like

```
[99.25, 14.74, 26.12, 20.91, 37.14, 79.03, 17.68,  28.4, ...., 0]
```

so when I print `print arrayF[0][0]` I receive `[`, where I need the output to be the 1st element of the 1st vector, which is 99.25.

I tried several ways using numpy, and writing the text file to CSV but nothing works, can you please assist me to solve this issue. You can access the text file through the following link give you an idea about its structure.
[text.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8ixib218ntw8ve0/text.txt?dl=0)

Comment: When you say `for vector in f`, what gets passed to your code in the `vector` variable is not a vector, but rather one entire line of the file (as a string). You want to do something like `for line in f` and write code inside the loop to split up each line into the tokens of interest (using regular-expressions and/or `str.split()`, for example) . Then make sure you convert those tokens to numeric values, before using them to fill up your array.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. The content of vector is as described in my post [99.25,........0], but as you said, it's parsed as string not as array. But is there an easier method than reg-expression???

Comment: If lines adhere to sample, you may strip the sqare brackets from the line and split on comma space and int() every list element coming out of rhe split. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with a string, you need to do the following steps to get a list of numbers from it:

1. Use `strip` to get rid of `[]`
2. Use `split(",")` to split the string at every comma and create a list of strings
3. Use map(float, vector) to convert it to a list of floats
4. Use list() to get an actual list rather than a mapped object

You should then be able to put this into your numpy matrix. It's not necessary to use `map(float, vector)` if using numpy though, because numpy will infer that they are floats automatically.

Here is a sample code:

```
myMtrx = np.empty((1137,1137))
f = open("text.txt", "r")

for idx, vector in enumerate(f):
    # vector = '[99.25, 14.74, 26.12, 20.91, 37.14, 79.03, 17.68,  28.4, 0]'
    vector = list(map(float, vector.strip("[]\n").split(",")))
    myMtrx[idx ,:] = vector
```

Comment: Implemented suggested code, but received following error `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 17.6]`

Comment: Does the first line in your file end with 17.6? It could be the newline character after it that could be causing the issue. Try adding \n inside strip()

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer if you're happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading string from your file, that you need to convert to list. A solution like this one may do the trick:

```
for line in f:
   vector = line.strip("[]").split(",")
   ...
```

- `strip` : remove all characters in "[]"  from begining and end of string
- `split`: transform string to list, cutting at each "," position

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
  f = open('first.txt').readlines()
  f = [i.strip('\n') for i in f]

  new_list = []
  final_list = []
  for i in f:
      new_list.append(i.split(' '))

  for i in new_list:
      final_list.append(map(int, i))

  print final_list
```

we read the contents into f, split them at the spaces and append them to new_list, and then map over each string row in the matrix formed and append that to final_list, which will give you the matrix you would like.